# Mirroring source code to 2 different Team Foundation Servers

Tags: c#, tfs, share, mirroring, codeplex

my Friends. I have my own TFS where I'm developing an application (only me). Now I would like to SHARE IT and make its source code public at Codeplex. So I went to the site, created a project and chose TFS as the source control system.

The problem comes that, in order to publish the code, I would have to change my current source control and it's a really tedious task. I would have to mirror the contents of my project to the Codeplex TFS to keep it updated. Sounds difficult, but...

... is there any way to replicate the contents of the TFS so my code can automatically be shared while keeping my current TFS setup without much hassle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about a regular TFS workspace, but if it's a GIT repository, you can define multiple "remotes" in your local GIT repo, so that it pushes changes to both your local TFS and Codeplex